# Cisco RV042G Multiple public IP

Tags: cisco, router

Is it possible for the RV042G or similar router to be configured with multiple public IP addresses on the one WAN interface?

Comment: What is your intended use and result in having multiple IP addresses assigned to the WAN interface ?  
Has your ISP already granted you more than one address, or do you know whether the upstream device allows routing for more than your current IP ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful.

Some proper Cisco routers allow for an "ip address ... secondary" command (http://goo.gl/Bqd1VK), but that's not quite the same, and I'm not seeing any mention of it in the RV042G's documentation.